# Find a subgroup of order $12$

Tags: group-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. If $|H|=4$ and for $g \in G$, $gH$ has order $3$ in $G/H$, find a subgroup of order $12$ in $G$.

**My Approach:** $|g| \in \{3,6,12\}$.
This is only thing i have calculated

Comment: If |g|=12 then it generates a group of order 12. If |g|=3 then your answer works. When |g|=6 use $<H, g^2>$.

Comment: thanks to your comment,i realised my approach was very much wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to look at things you wrote is following.

> Take subgroup $K$ generated by $H$ and $g$; this clearly makes sense.

This contains $H$, and $H$ is normal in it (why?).

Further, $K/H$ is generated by just $gH$, which has order $3$, and so $K/H$ is of order $3$.

From the order of normal subgroup and order of quotient group, you get order of $K$, what it is?

Comment: You mean K is generated by H union g